# How do you pass additional information from a form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following PHP code:

```
echo "<form name='CLChange' method='post' action=''>";
echo "<td><select name='NewClearanceLevel'>\n";
for($i = 1; $i < $ClearanceLevel; $i++)
{
    echo "<option value='" . $i . "'>" . $i . "\n";
}
echo"<input type='submit' value='Change'></td></form>";
```

I want to be able to pass on an other value representing the current table row (This creates a table with which I should be able to make changes to an individual user). It has a row for every user. It looks roughly like this:

```
User          ID      Clearance Level    New Clearance Level

User 1        1       4                  (Drop down list and submit button)

User 2        2       3                  (Drop down list and submit button)

User 3        3       1                  (Drop down list and submit button)
```

Each drop down list and button is an individual form.

How can I do it so that I can pass an additional value as to know which user I am talking about? Or is there any other way to know which is the name of the form passed?

Comment: You don't need to use `&nbsp;` to format tabular data; just use regular spaces and the `{}` button.

Comment: Use an `<input type="hidden" value="foo" />` in your form.  FWIW, you're missing your `</select>` tag as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<form name='CLChange' method='post' action=''>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='userId' value='" . $userId . "' />";
echo "<td><select name='NewClearanceLevel'>\n";
for($i = 1; $i < $ClearanceLevel; $i++)
{
    echo "<option value='" . $i . "'>" . $i . "\n";
}
echo"<input type='submit' value='Change'></td></form>";
```

Comment: The code you've put in there is not valid at all. I won't say it won't work, but it's not valid...

Comment: And for the record, if the option and its values are the same, then `value=""` attribute is not necessary.

Comment: It's pretty common to see both the `value` and text node set for an `OPTION`, even if they're the same. Not sure why, but I see it all over the place.

Comment: I simply used the original author's code to facilitate the demonstration of hidden input elements. I apologize for not including a disclaimer.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `hidden` input type:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

The hidden form element is a tried and true solution, however you can also tack on some url params to the form action target:

```
echo "<form name='CLChange' method='post' action='yourscript.php?uid=$userId'>";
```

And then of course you retrieve it in yourscript.php:

```
$userid = (int)$_GET['uid'];
```